# use session cookies per specific browsertab

Tags: php, ajax, session-cookies

I currently have a form that allows a user to edit entries. However, it doesn't seem to be possible to use 1 (specific) cookie per tab. Whenever a user edits an entry, the record in the last tab gets updated.

I've tried the following in my main script (eventfilters.php):

```
<?php
$cookie_name = $_SESSION['username'].md5(time());
session_name($cookie_name);
setcookie(session_name($cookie_name),session_id(),time()+"300");
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }

if (isset($_GET['edit'])){  
    // Pass cookiename in url variable $cookie, so it gets caught by $_GET['cookie']
    echo '<form action="eventfilters.php?save&cookie='.session_name().'" method="post">';

} else if (isset($_GET['save'])){
    if(isset($_GET['cookie'])){
        error_log("SAVE ".$_GET['cookie']); // Displays cookie url variable set by form action.
        error_log("LOW ".$_SESSION['level_low']); 
        // Displays correct session value received from ajax
    }
}

?>
```

`

The ajaxcode (also in eventfilters.php) contains this (called few times when page is already loaded):

`$.post("include/severitygroups.php",{'cookie_name': "<?php echo $cookie_name; ?>", 'serialized_sev_groups': serialized_sev_groups}, function(data){});`

This seems to pass the right cookiename to the other script, which successfully seems to return $_SESSION['level_low'] (as it appears in the error_log).

```
<?php
include('pdodb.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }
$cookie_name = $_POST['cookie_name'];
error_log("SCRIPT ".$cookie_name);
error_log("COOKIEDATA ".$_COOKIE["$cookie_name"]);

// populating $_SESSION['level_low']
?>
```

It seems that the $_GET['save'] is populating the wrong sessions (initialised by the last loaded instance of eventfilters.php), even when the $_GET['save'] logs the right $_SESSION['level_low'] to the errorlog.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it. The best way to do it, is with Ajax, so, you will pass an "ID" to each tab (or page) like:

```
editPost.php?id=someID
```

And, each time you press **save**, you should send your **content** with your **id** param to save it.

Comment: Best possible way. I'd suggest generating some random ID and using that throughout the same page.

Comment: I also have other fields in the form, that are saved in the $_GET['save'] like this:

$_SESSION['comments'] = $_POST['comments'];

EDIT: I think it get it, thanks!